# Recuperar valor IEnumerable em Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Bom dia, criei uma solicitação de ajuda sobre isso antes e foi marcado como duplicado e alguns que tentaram me ajudar, mas acho que entenderam errado o que estou com dificuldade.

Eu tenho essas duas classes:

```
public class TabelaPreco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int TipoServicoId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemTabelaPreco> ListaItemTabelaPreco { get; set;
}

public class ItemTabelaPreco
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorUnitario { get; set; }
    public int QtdPacote { get; set; }
    public decimal ValorPacote { get; set; }
    public int TabelaPrecoId { get; set; }
}
```

Dentro da class TabelaPreco tenho uma lista de item do tipo ItemTabelaPreco.

Recupero sem problemas os valores do banco de dados tanto da TabelaPreço quanto da ItemTabelaPreco para exibir na view de edição, a ListaItemTabelaPreco vem preenchida sem problemas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu problema é que quando clico em Salvar que dá o Post para o controller, a ListaItemTabelaPreco vem NULL sempre, os outros campos vem os valores corretamente, tentei utilizar alguns exemplos que o pessoal indicou de partial e viewmodel, mas continuou vindo null.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(TabelaPreco tabelaPrecoModel)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá @Max. Na verdade, eu acho que você que não entendeu as respostas. O que você deseja é enviar uma lista de dados no POST, correto? Então é isso que as outras respostas falam. Caso queira outros exemplos, [todas essas respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=BeginCollectionItem) falam da mesma coisa. Você pode fazer por `for()`, utilizando o `BeginCollectionItem` ou de alguma outra forma que encontrar, mas o problema me parece o mesmo. Caso tenha alguma dúvida específica com o uso de alguma dessas formas, você pode abrir uma pergunta mais específica, que será mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Comment: @Randrade, realmente seguindo um dos tópicos que você indicou consegui fazer funcionar e era o que o pessoal estava dizendo mesmo, eu que não estava conseguindo entender. Mas você ou algum outro poderia por favor, me explicar o porque dessa forma funcionar e da outra não? Obrigado!

Comment: Ficarei feliz em explicar. Mas, para deixar no "acervo" do site, peço que abra uma outra pergunta com essa dúvida, assim ficará para todos que tiverem essa mesma dúvida